# Cheap RFID/NFC reader and *writer* which has a programmable (serial port?) interface?

Tags: nfc, rfid, programmable

I would like to use an ESP32, would settle for Raspberry PI. I seek an RFID and/or NFC reader/writer, which I can use C/C++/Python code to read and write the serial number (terminology?) of a tag.

Cheap & cheerful, but also easy to interface with, which is why I mention serial port. USB interface seems simplest, Grove would be great. I would happily pay extra for WiFi, even BLE, interface.

An AliExpress link would be a real bonus.

Answer (score 0):

## NXP PN532

[image]

The NXP PN532 is a highly flexible RFID/NFC reader, [supporting read and write for ISO / IEC14443A / MIFARE (including Classic 1K and Classic 4K)](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/nxp/data-sheets/PN532_C1.pdf). It supports communication via 3.3V TTL UART at any baud rate, I2C, or SPI. Once connected to a device of your choice (ESP32, Arduino, Raspbery Pi), you should be able to easily interface with it and use it in your language of choice. It's also well supported by [libnfc](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc), which means you can plug it into any Linux/Mac/Windows computer using an FTDI cable. I'm recommending it over the (also quite popular) [RC522](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid), since the RC522 is RFID only and does not support NFC.

In terms of a carrier, I'd normally recommend [this breakout board by Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/364), which also [includes first-party support for CircuitPython](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PN532) but it seems to be out of stock. In the meantime, [this relatively generic module should be fine](https://www.makerfabs.com/pn532-nfc-module-v3.html); just make sure you get one with a real V3 version, as there seem to be a lot of non-functional fakes out in the wild. If really want Grove compatibility and you only need the NFC functionality, you may want to use the [Grove NFC from Seeed Studio](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove_NFC/); as far as I know there's no reason it shouldn't also support RFID, but it doesn't seemed to be mentioned in the documentation at all.